# Why is my stored procedure receiving a null parameter?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

Ok, this is a curly one. I'm working on some Delphi code that I didn't write, and I'm encountering a very strange problem. One of my stored procedures' parameters is coming through as `null`, even though it's definitely being sent `1`.

The Delphi code uses a TADOQuery to execute the stored procedure (anonymized):

```
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := "exec MyStoredProcedure :Foo,:Bar,:Baz,:Qux,:Smang,:Jimmy";
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName("Foo").Value := Integer(someFunction()); 
 // other parameters all set similarly
 ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

`Integer(SomeFunction())` currently always returns 1 - I checked with the debugger.

However, in my stored proc ( altered for debug purposes ):

```
create procedure MyStoredProcedure (
    @Foo int, @Bar int, @Baz int,
    @Qux int, @Smang int, @Jimmy varchar(20) 
) as begin
    -- temp debug
    if ( @Foo is null ) begin
        insert into TempLog values ( "oh crap" )
    end
    -- do the rest of the stuff here..
end
```

`TempLog` does indeed end up with "oh crap" in it (side question: there must be a better way of debugging stored procs: what is it?).

Here's an example trace from profiler:

```
exec [MYDB]..sp_procedure_params_rowset N'MyStoredProcedure',1,NULL,NULL

declare @p3 int
set @p3=NULL
exec sp_executesql 
    N'exec MyStoredProcedure @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6',
    N'@P1 int OUTPUT,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int',
    @p3 output,1,1,1,0,200
select @p3
```

This looks a little strange to me. Notice that it's using @p3 *and* @P3 - could this be causing my issue?

The other strange thing is that it seems to depend on which TADOConnection I use.

The project is a dll which is passed a TADOConnection from another application. It calls all the stored procedures using this connection.

If instead of using this connection, I first do this:

```
ConnectionNew := TADOQuery.Create(ConnectionOld.Owner);
ConnectionNew.ConnectionString := ConnectionOld.ConnectionString;
TADOQuery1.Connection := ConnectionNew;
```

Then the issue does not occur! The trace from this situation is this:

```
exec [MYDB]..sp_procedure_params_rowset N'MyStoredProcedure',1,NULL,NULL

declare @p1 int
set @p1=64
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,
    N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 varchar(20)',
    N'exec MyStoredProcedure @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6',
    1
select @p1

SET FMTONLY ON exec sp_execute 64,0,0,0,0,0,' ' SET FMTONLY OFF

exec sp_unprepare 64

SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF

exec sp_executesql 
    N'exec MyStoredProcedure @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6',
    N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 varchar(20)',
    1,1,1,3,0,'400.00'
```

Which is a bit much for lil ol' me to follow, unfortunately. What sort of TADOConnection options could be influencing this?

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:** [Update below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137530/why-is-my-stored-procedure-receiving-a-null-parameter#177214) (didn't want to make this question any longer :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, progress is made.. sort of.

@Robsoft was correct, setting the parameter direction to `pdInput` fixed the issue.

I traced into the VCL code, and it came down to `TParameters.InternalRefresh.RefreshFromOleDB`. This function is being called when I set the SQL.Text. Here's the (abridged) code:

```
function TParameters.InternalRefresh: Boolean;
  procedure RefreshFromOleDB;
    // ..
        if OLEDBParameters.GetParameterInfo(ParamCount, PDBPARAMINFO(ParamInfo), @NamesBuffer) = S_OK then
          for I := 0 to ParamCount - 1 do
            with ParamInfo[I] do
            begin
              // ..
              Direction := dwFlags and $F;       // here's where the wrong value comes from
              // ..
            end;
     // ..
  end;
  // ..
end;
```

So, [`OLEDBParameters.GetParameterInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714917(VS.85).aspx) is returning the wrong flags for some reason.

I've verified that with the original connection, `(dwFlags and $F)` is `2` (`DBPARAMFLAGS_ISOUTPUT`), and with the new connection, it's `1` (`DBPARAMFLAGS_ISINPUT`).

I'm not really sure I want to dig any deeper than that, for now at least.

Until I have more time and inclination, I'll just make sure all parameters are set to `pdInput` before I open the query. 
Unless anyone has any more bright ideas now..?

Anyway, thanks everyone for your suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1):

In my programs, I have **lots** of code very similar to your first snippet, and I haven't encountered this problem.

Is that **actually** your code, or is that how you've represented the problem for us to understand? Is the text for the SQL stored in your DFM or populated dynamically?

I was wondering if perhaps somehow the Params property of the query had already got a list of parameters defined/cached, in the IDE, and that might explain why P1 was being seen as output (which is almost certainly causing your NULL problem).

Just before you set the ParamByName.Value, try

```
ParamByName("Foo").ParamType=ptInput;
```

I'm not sure why you changing the connection string would also fix this, unless it's resetting the internal sense of the parameters for that query.

Under TSQLQuery, the Params property of a query gets reset/recreated whenever the SQL.Text value is changed (I'm not sure if that's true for a TADOQuery mind you), so that first snippet of yours ought to have caused any existing Params information to have been dropped.

If the 'ParamByname.ParamType' suggestion above does fix it for you, then surely there's something happening to the query elsewhere (at create-time? on the form?) that is causing it to think Foo is an output parameter...

does that help at all? :-)

Answer (score 0):

caveat: i don't know delphi, but this issue rings a faint bell and so i'm interested in it

do you get the same result if you use a TADOStoredProc instead of a TADOQuery? [see delphi 5 developers guide](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/ado_comp.html)

also, it looks like the first trace does no prepare call and thinks @P1 is an output paramer in the execute, while the second trace does a prepare call with @P1 as an output but does not show @P1 as an output in the execute step - is this significant? it does seem odd, and so may be a clue

you might also try replacing the function call with a constant 1

good luck, and please let us know what you find out!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have some parameters mismatch left over from the previous use of your ADOQuery.

Have you tried to reset your parameters after changing the SQL.Text:

```
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.Refresh;
```

Also you could try to clear the parameters and explicitly recreate them:

```
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.CreateParameter('Foo', ftInteger, pdInput, 0, 1);
  [...]
```

I think changing the connection actually forces an InternalRefresh of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName("Foo").Value = Integer(someFunction());
```

Don't they use `:=` for assignment in Object Pascal?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I've start working on c# as well as Delphi and I'm now constantly making that mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

@Constantin

It must be a typo from the Author of the question.

@Blorgbeard

Hmmm... When you change SQL of a TADOQuery, is good use to 
clear the parameters and recreate then using CreateParameter.
I would not rely on ParamCheck in runtime - since it leaves 
the parameters' properties mostly undefined.
I've had such type of problem when relying on ParamCheck to
autofill the parameters - is rare but occurs.
Ah, if you go the CreateParameter route, create as first 
parameter the @RETURN_VALUE one, since it'll catch the returned
value of the MSSQL SP.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've had a problem like this was when the DB Provider couldn't distinguish between Output (always sets it to null) and InputOutput (uses what you provide) parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue using TADOQuery to retrieve some LDAP info, there is a bug in the TParameter.InternalRefresh function that causes an access violation even if your query has no parameters.

To solve this, simply set TADOQuery.ParamCheck to false.